# output after first cycle in a while loop

Tags: java

My question is not about general game algorithm. When i answer "true" to the question "Do you want to continue? Enter true or false.", program outputs:

```
"Player one, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)! 
 Player two, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)!"
```

So i can enter values in first cycle but not in second. How can i fix it? Thanks.

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String playerOne;
        String playerTwo;
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean playAgain = true;

        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Player one, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)! ");
            playerOne = myScan.nextLine();        
            System.out.println("Player two, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)! ");
            playerTwo = myScan.nextLine();




            if (playerOne.equals("scissors") && playerTwo.equals("rock"))
            {
            System.out.println("Player one lost! Playr two won!");
            } 

              else if (playerOne.equals("scissors") && playerTwo.equals("paper")) 
              {
              System.out.println("Player one won! Player two lost!");
              } 


              else if (playerOne.equals("rock") && playerTwo.equals("paper")) 
              {
               System.out.println("Player one lost! Player two won!");
              }


              else if (playerOne.equals("rock") && playerTwo.equals("scissors")) 
              {
              System.out.println("Player one won! Player two lost!");
              }


              else if (playerOne.equals("paper") && playerTwo.equals("scissors")) 
              {
              System.out.println("Player one lost! Player two won!");
              }


              else if (playerOne.equals("paper") && playerTwo.equals("rock")) 
              {
              System.out.println("Player one won! Player two lost!");
              }

              System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Enter true or false.");
              playAgain = myScan.nextBoolean();

        }while(playAgain);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your program appears to work as it should. What do you mean by "first cycle but not in second"? How are you defining "cycle"?

Comment: It work first time,but when i input "true", program doesn't ask for inputs like first time, but outputs 
Player one, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)! 
Player two, throw your shape(rock, paper, scissors)!

Comment: so it is skipping inputs if i want to continue the game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `Scanner` only reads the boolean you request with `nextBoolean` and nothing else, not even the following line ending. The line ending then remains in the input stream and is returned as an empty line when the loop comes around and you ask for `nextLine`.

What you'll want to do instead is to read a complete line instead of just a boolean for `playAgain`, and interpret that manually (suggestedly with something like `myScan.nextLine().equals("yes")`).